# Cypress cy.request .then chaining returning undefined

Tags: cypress

I'm upgrading Cypress from 10.2.0 to 10.11.0 and I'm encountering some behaviour I'm trying to understand.

In the second `.then`, the `response` is undefined. This had previously worked on 10.2.0.

```
public makeRequest(params) {
  return cy.request({
    ...params
    })
    .then((response) => {
       // do something with response
    });
}

this.makeRequest(params)
   .then((response) => {
     // response is undefined
    });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I have checked the changelogs for every version since 10.3.0 and cannot find anything to explain this behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you returning anything in the `.then()` within the `makeRequest` function?

Comment: @agoff Thank you, this led me on the right path.

I was trying to add a return statement in `.then` but I was performing async tasks there, so I added a third `.then` to return the response.

Comment: Primarily because I forgot `cy` commands are async. Though still not sure why this is a breaking change upgrading to 10.11.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress (**version 10.11.0** and previous versions) returns the last command result taken within the `cy.request().then()` chain, when there is no explicit return value given.

For example, if `// do some async tasks` is a non-Cypress asynchronous query, the `response` is returned:

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com');

function makeRequest(params) {
  return cy.request(params)
    .then((response) => {

      // do some async tasks
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(response.title)
        expect(response.body.title).to.eq('delectus aut autem')       // passes
      }, 1000)
    })
}

makeRequest({url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'})
  .then(response => {
    expect(response.body.title).to.eq('delectus aut autem')           // passes
  })
```

If however you issue more Cypress commands inside the `// do some async tasks` block, the last chained "subject" changes, and you get a different return value

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com');

function makeRequest(params) {
  return cy.request(params)
    .then((response) => {

      // do some async tasks
      cy.get('h1')               // changes "subject" from response to <h1> element 
    })
}

makeRequest({url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)  // not your response, but the last "subject" found above

    expect(response.text()).to.eq('Example Domain')                   // passes
  })
```

Comment: Is there a reason why OP says this worked in 10.2 and doesn't in 10.11? It _sounds_ like a behavior change but I didn't dive in deep enough to the release notes to find anything :D

Comment: +1 on @agoff comment. 

`// do some async tasks` block would contain some `cy.log`, if I want to continue passing `response` to the next `.then` block, how could I achieve this?

Comment: I didn't find any difference between ver 10.2.0 and 10.11.0. It would be a major breaking change which Cypress would only do in a major number change (e.g 11.0.0). As for passing response on, yes you will need to `return response` to avoid any subject changes that happened in "// do some async commands".

Comment: I think "async tasks" is confusing the issue - ***only*** if they are Cypress commands that alter the "subject", then you need to explicitly return the request's response to keep it on the chain.

Comment: See [.then() #Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then#Yields), there is actually no need to return response - but it cannot hurt to be explicit.

Comment: It's also another issue if you return the response in the same .then block where you're performing cypress async tasks. As Cypress will tell you, you cannot perform sync and async tasks in the same block.

Comment: That problem is fixed by `return cy.wrap(response)` or just `cy.wrap(response)`. The `cy.wrap()` put's the response value back on the queue after preceding commands have run. Note - as long as you haven't tried to modify `response`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a return returns the response

```
public makeRequest(params) {
  return cy.request({
    ...params
    })
    .then((response) => {
       // do something with response
       return response;
    });
}
```

If you are doing some async tasks in `makeRequest.then()`, do your async tasks and return response in another `.then`. E.g:

```
public makeRequest(params) {
  return cy.request({
    ...params
    })
    .then((response) => {
       // do some async tasks
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    });
}
```